# How does recursion work internally in python (source code of recursion)?

Tags: python, recursion

I would like to understand the internal work of recursion. Can I write my own recursion for python?

For example, now we have following function:

```
def fact(n):
    return n*fact(n)
```

How can I change the return command and change the functionality of it, like the following:

```
def fact(n):
    my_return  n*fact(n)
```

In this case, I want to change the internal work of return and use my_returne, and also with this, I want to control stack differently.

Comment: recursive function calls work *the same* as any other function call

Comment: _How can I change the return command and change the functionality of it, like the following_ ..... _In this case, I want to change the internal work of return and use my_returne_ That doesn't actually explain what functionality you're trying to change/achieve.

Comment: okay. How can I control the function call? like, I would change the internal work of return.

Comment: @MerujMartirosyan you would need to modify the python interpreter source-code and re-compile the runtime and then use that.

Comment: Is there any documentation to learn about it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to understand the guts of how Python works, I highly recommend reading the documentation for the built-in modules under the ["Language Services"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/language.html) heading, particularly the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) and [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) modules. Python exposes, as importable and Python-runnable modules, all of its parsing capabilities. You can see, use, and tinker with its parsing of code, how it generates bytecode, and its core execution.

I'm not sure if this really helps, but [`RETURN_VALUE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-RETURN_VALUE) is its own opcode in Python's bytecode, so aside from creating your own bytecode manually or screwing with the parser results, there's probably no other way to get the `return` keyword's behavior. The actual implementation of how that behaves is going to be implementation-dependent (CPython might do it differently from Pypy, for example), so you'd need to be more specific in your question, or just dig into their source code for that opcode.

That said, there's nothing stopping you from creating your own stack as a list and pushing/popping stack frames to/from it yourself, besides the sheer insanity of the act. E.g.,

```
stack = []

def my_pseudo_func():
    global stack
    args, kwargs = stack[-1]
    x, = args
    # do some stuff
    my_return_result = x + 5
    ###
    stack.pop()
    stack.append(my_return_result)

stack.append(((3,), {}))
my_pseudo_func()
result = stack.pop()
assert result == 8
```

Comment: There actually isn't anything particularly insane about using your own stack-based solution, it is often the best way to change a recursive algorithm into an iterative one, which is generally the preferred way of doing things in Python